# Change disabled background color of mat-form-field on Angular 15

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can we change the background colour of text input on angular 15 when its disabled (also outline colors)?

I tried `mdc-text-field--disabled` and override outline css, but none worked.

*Current output when disabled*

[image]

```
.mat-mdc-input-element {
      color: blue !important;
 }
    
.mdc-text-field--disabled {
      margin-top: 5px !important;
      height: 45px !important;
      font-family: 'Roboto';
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: 500;
      background-color: blue !important;
      border-radius: 0px !important;
      letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

.mdc-text-field {
  margin-top: 5px !important;
  height: 45px !important;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}



.mat-mdc-form-field-error-wrapper {
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mdc-notched-outline__leading,
.mdc-notched-outline__notch,
.mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  border-color: blue !important;
}


.mdc-text-field--disabled .mdc-notched-outline__leading,
.mdc-text-field--disabled .mdc-notched-outline__notch,
.mdc-text-field--disabled .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  border-color: blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
::ng-deep .mdc-text-field--disabled
{
  background-color:lightgray !important;
  outline: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

if need only one place use parent class to prevent other changing in other places

Answer (score 0):

I put the .mdc-text-field--disabled class in the global style sheet (e.g. styles.scss) and it worked. No need to use ng-deep nor important